# Setting size of popup page to the size of selected div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening new popup page using `window.open`and I want to make size of new page same size of a specific `div` and I want my page to focus on this `div`.

For example I have this structure,

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="main"> 
        <div id="top"></div>  
        <div id="bottom"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open my new popup page,  I want new window just show the `div` with the `id=top`

I can do that calculating size of div and scrolling page to `div` I guess, I want to ask if there is easier way.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

```
var divHeight = $("#top").height();
var divWidth = $("#top").width();

var w=window.open('','', 'width=0,height=0');
w.resizeTo(divWidth, divHeight);
w.focus();
```

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/deepakpmishra/KaAas/3/

Resize the result window and the popup window size changes.

**EDIT**

You can resize the div to fit the window, but cannot do it other way around.

The div that needs to be created inside popup, its dimensions should be predefined. So that the popup window size and div size can be of the same size.
Make `top` div fit screen in the popup.

```
#top
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

And specify a suitable size of the popup when creating it. Lets say,

```
var w=window.open('','', 'width=100,height=200');
```

You have to use `$("#top").focus` in the popup for focusing on the div. And the popup contain the address of the html code you have provided in the question.

Comment: I was doing similar thing, do you have any idea about how to focus on specific div? The new page is the same as old page. I want it just to show `top` div. Size is ok but i want it to focus on this div also.

Comment: CSS can help you with that and just give the popup a suitable size.